# Get a particular choice from ENUM in django field

Tags: django, django-models, enums, django-admin, django-orm

I have a model. Lets say

```
class Colors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=choices(Type))
```

And there is also a ENUM class

```
class Type(Enum):
    Red = 0
    Green = 1
    Blue = 2
```

As I have to use Inlines in Admin so I have used Proxy model inheritence

```
class ColorIns(Colors):

    class Meta:
        proxy=True
```

And we have Boy and Girl class having fav color. So that a boy and girl can have same fav color

```
class BoyGirlMap(models.Model):
    color = models.ForeignKey(ColorIns)
    boy = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    girl = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Now I have to get **only Blue color from the ENUM class**. Excluding red and green.
How can we filter it out so that in admin only Blue color will come excluding Green, Red.

**How can I override type field from Colors model in ColorIns model?**

Now in admin I am getting all the colors which was created before. But I have to show only Blue color. And then add boy or girl name using InlineModelAdmin. Be it StackedInline or TabularInline

My Admin.py file is

```
class BoyGirlMapInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BoyGirlMap
    extra = 0

@admin.register(ColorIns, site=admin.site)
class ColorInsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ BoyGirlMapInline, ]
    fields=('name',)
```

Comment: I find the modeling quite odd. Can you specify *what* you aim to model? Right now I think there is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Actually this is a sample model. As I can't share the real model.
I want to get only one option from ENUM in my ColorIns model. Just overriding the type field

Comment: Do I need to use Abstract Base class Model Inheritence in place of Proxy model Inheritence?

Comment: I just want to get blue color from ENUM class. Excluding red and green. How can I override the type field?

Comment: Do you just want your  choices to be a subset of that enum or specifically restricted in the admin panel?

Comment: Actually there were values for all the colors from previous data.
As I need to use inline so I used proxy model inheritence. Now I need to restrict it to blue color in admin. But I am not getting how to override type field

Comment: I want the choices to be restricted in admin page. So only blue color will be shown in ColorIns admin page

Comment: Anyone there who could help me???